# What is the difference between ampliative, abductive and inductive arguments?

Tags: logic, argumentation

I know all these arguments are kind of the same but what is the border dividing them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are "if smoke then fire" arguments deductive or inductive?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/46118/are-if-smoke-then-fire-arguments-deductive-or-inductive) Ampliative means non-deductive, i.e. inductive and/or abductive.