# What is the difference between inductive and abductive reasoning?

Tags: logic, argumentation, critical-thinking

I would deeply appreciate it if you would answer this question, since I do not know or understand exactly the difference between inductive reasoning and abductive reasoning, which is a problem for me in my next philosophy evaluations.

Comment: This question has been answered several times on PSE. Use search term “induction abduction “.

Comment: Related [Are “if smoke then fire” arguments deductive or inductive?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/46118/9148)